# Apache phoenix PySpark dependencies

Tags: pyspark, cloudera-cdh, apache-phoenix

I want to query a Phoenix table from spark using spark connector. In Hortonwork environment i used to do following

***pyspark --jars
/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/phoenix/phoenix-spark2.jar,/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/phoenix/phoenix-client.jar,/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/phoenix/phoenix-server.jar***

and then run my code.

Recently when trying to run the same thing on Cloudera 7.1.5 i am unable to find phoenix-spark2.jar and phoenix-client and phoenix-server. The spark connector documentation https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.6/phoenix-access-data/phoenix-access-data.pdf also doesn't specify guide. Please guide me what jars should i use.

-Ajaz

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. As Per documentation follow the following process. Once done no need to specify and additional jars when starting pyspark session.

Go to the Spark service.
Click the Configuration tab.
Select Scope > Gateway.
Select Category > Advanced.
Locate the Spark Client Advanced Configuration Snippet (Safety Valve) for spark-conf/spark-defaults.conf property or search for it by typing its name in the Search box.
Add the following properties to ensure that all required Phoenix and HBase platform dependencies are available on the classpath for the Spark executors and drivers:
Phoenix client JARs: Note following may vary based on the CDP version, check the spark phoenix documentation for the correct jar.

******spark.executor.extraClassPath=phoenix-client-[***VERSION***].jar
spark.driver.extraClassPath=phoenix-client-[***VERSION***].jar******

Enter a Reason for change, and then click Save Changes to commit the changes.
Restart the role and service when Cloudera Manager prompts you to restart.